# When is the linear combination of matrixes invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

As you can embedd the complex numbers or the quaternions in $M_m(\mathbb{R})$ I was wondering if their is a nice criteria for a given subset $\left\{A_1,...,A_n \right\} \subset M_m(\mathbb{R})$ such that it satisfies the following criteria.

$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i A_i$ is invertible if and only if $0 \neq (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: If we additionally assume that your subset is closed under multiplication, then the [only examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) will be the representations of the complex numbers and of the quaternions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom And if we don't ask beeing closed under multiplication we get that cliffordalgebras give a possible subset. (namely matrixes satisfieing $I_i I_j = - I_j I_i$ and $I_i^2=-1$

Comment: So called orthogonal designs give examples. They are, indeed, very closely related to Clifford algebras. Octonions also give such a linear space, and you can keep increasing $n$ at the cost of (exponential) growth of $m$. Look up Radon-Hurwitz matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Your criterion is true if and only if your set $\{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ consists of a single invertible matrix.

Namely, if some $A_j$ is not invertible then the nontrivial linear combination $$0\cdot A_1 + \cdots + 0 \cdot A_{j-1} + 1 \cdot A_j + 0\cdot A_{j+1} + \cdots + 0\cdot A_n = A_j$$
is not invertible.

On the other hand, if there are two different invertible matrices $A_i$ and $A_j$ then

$$\alpha A_i + \beta A_j \text{ is invertible } \iff A_{i}^{-1}(\alpha A_i + \beta A_j) \text{ is invertible } \iff \alpha I + \beta A_{i}^{-1}A_j  \text{ is invertible } $$
which is true if and only if $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} \notin \sigma( A_{i}^{-1}A_j)$, which is nonempty. Hence, if you pick $\alpha \in \sigma( A_{i}^{-1}A_j)$ and $\beta = 1$ then $\alpha A_i + \beta A_j$ is not invertible.

Comment: This only works if you assume that the scalar field is the complex numbers.  If we take only real scalars, the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
form a well known example.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom This was exactly the example which sparked the question. thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: @Netivolu you should probably add that to your question, then.  Another important example are the $4 \times 4$ matrices given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well those where what i was talking about when i started my post with 
"As you can embedd the complex numbers or the quaternions in $M_m(\mathbb{R})$".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Maybe that wasn't clear enough?

Comment: @Netivolu ah, I wasn't reading closely enough :P

Comment: @Netivolu you should probably specify that you wanted to consider $x_i \in \Bbb R$ as opposed to complex coefficients, though

Comment: What if some matrices are not diagonalizable?